# WndProc message = 49619 -what is it?

Tags: c#, wndproc, window-messages

I'm debugging a dragging bug in wpf and have subscribed to wndproc.  I'm getting a message ID of 49619 with wparam=0 and lparam=0.  I've exhausted my google efforts and have been unable to uncover what the name of this window message is.

If you know, great. If you can provide a website that includes it in its listing of window messages, that's even better.

hex value = 0xC1D3

Comment: This may shed some light on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931(v=vs.85).aspx, notably the 0xC000 through 0xFFFF range defined at runtime with `RegisterWindowMessage`.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterHuene  The link did indeed have the answer.  If you post it as an answer i'll accept it.    "Message numbers in the fourth range (0xC000 through 0xFFFF) are defined at run time when an application calls the RegisterWindowMessage function to retrieve a message number for a string. All applications that register the same string can use the associated message number for exchanging messages. The actual message number, however, is not a constant and cannot be assumed to be the same between different sessions."

Comment: I'm lazy and rarely submit answers for questions that require a one line explanation, so I'll just upvote whomever does submit an answer instead :)

Comment: Best list of window messages i've found:  http://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at WM_USER.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931(v=vs.85).aspx

RegisterWindowMessage

> Message numbers in the fourth range (0xC000 through 0xFFFF) are defined at run time when an application calls the RegisterWindowMessage function to retrieve a message number for a string. All applications that register the same string can use the associated message number for exchanging messages. The actual message number, however, is not a constant and cannot be assumed to be the same between different sessions.

Comment: links can go dead.  Can you paste the applicable quotes from the link into your answer, please?

Comment: If you're going to do a copy/paste answer, at least do a clean complete answer.

Comment: Fixed up my "copy-paste answer" to be more complete.